# Laravel 5 preventing 'use'

Tags: laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

Is there a way to prevent using 'use' for everything. In Laravel 4 I never used 'use' and everything just worked. I'm now finding out I have to include everything, even 'DB' `use DB`. This is extremely frustrating and time consuming looking all this up.

My question is, is there an easier way to include everything?

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Customer;
use DB;

class HomeController extends Controller {

}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with `it's time consuming`? What editor or IDE are you using that can't import namespaced classes? Anyway, it has nothing to do with Laravel. That's how namespaces work in PHP.

Comment: This is because `DB` is in the root namespace and your controllers are in `App\Http\Controllers`.

Comment: I strongly suggest you find an editor or IDE that adds `use` statements automatically. I mostly never even touch the imports section of my classes... Personally I'm very fond of PhpStorm but there a lot of tools out there that have this functionality. Maybe even the one you're using right now and you just don't know it ;)

Comment: namespace in sweet. Please get used to them. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not really -- this is the Brave New Namespaced world of PHP 5.3+.  Your class file above lives in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace, which means when you type something like

```
$object = new SomeClass;
```

PHP will assume you mean the class `App\Http\Controllers\SomeClass`.

You'll either, as you complained about, need to use `use`, **or** you'll need to use the full classname (with a leading `\` to let PHP know to start from the global namespace) whenever you want to use a class

```
class HomeController extends Controller {
    public function someFunction()
    {
        $result = \DB::query(...);  
        $customer = new \App\Models\Customer;
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is question is old but I found you can do this based on information from a tutorial by Tejas Jasani: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/upgrading-from-laravel-4-2-to-5-in-web

Here are the key steps:

1 - Add the app/Http/Controllers directory to the "autoload" classmap directive of your composer.json file.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Http/Controllers"
    ],
```

2 - Remove the namespace from the abstract app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php base class.

3 - In app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php file, set the namespace property to null

```
protected $namespace = null;
```

4 - Run "composer dump-autoload" from the command line.